# How to alter hive table?

Tags: hive

we have table in hive like bellow,

```
create external table caremanagermongo(
id int  ,
cregiver_id int ,
patient_id int ,
caremanager_id int ,
provider_id int ,
is_active int ,
createddate timestamp ,
createdby String 
);
```

if we need  to alter this table by adding

```
stored by "org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler" 
 with serdeproperties ( "mongo.column.mapping" =     "id,cregiver_id,patient_id,caremanager_id,provider_id,is_active,createddate,createdby" ) 
tblproperties ( "mongo.host" = "localhost", "mongo.port" = "27017", 
"mongo.db" = "careticker",  "mongo.collection" = "caremanager" )
```

how it is possible, can you please provide the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

step-1  : when you create external table without using stored by , then it is a - **external-native** table

step-2 : you are trying to alter it with stored by -  to make it **external-non-native**. (which is not possible,according to my understanding)

There's no way possible to convert a native to non-native as per my understanding.

by the way, **ALTER TABLE is not yet supported for non-native tables**, as per the cwiki > hive >storagehandlers

hope this helps :)

Comment: Storage handlers are associated with a table when it(means table) is created via the new STORED BY clause. so create the non-native-external table in single shot. it works.